# Lenovo T400s - where is the Windows 7 OEM sticker?

Tags: windows-7, installation, lenovo-laptop

I recently bought one in the US. I ordered it with Windows 7 professional 64 bit.

I now want to make a clean installation without the OEM software, but I can't seem to see the sticker with the Windows 7 key on the bottom of the computer.

Is this supposed to be this way? How can I obtain my license?

Also, is it recommended to have a clean installation and get rid of the Lenovo software stuff?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know about Lenovo, but Dell has started sticking the OEM stickers under the battery.  Have you checked there?

EDIT:  If you look at [this service manual](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/45m2271_02.pdf) on page 137, it shows that it is directly under the battery.

Comment: Ayayay - you beat me to posting the answer. I searched google images and saw someone taking the computer apart - there I saw the sticker sitting nicely. Thanks!  
What an inconvenient place!

Comment: That makes sense. Placing the sticker and the instructions to find it in a convenient place for the average user to find... sometimes I just don't get these decision.

Comment: I like it.  I can't tell you how many stickers we've seen rub off because of wear.  It's no longer an issue if the sticker is under the battery!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make a clean installation without the OEM software, but
> I can't seem to see the CoA sticker with the Windows 7 key on the
> bottom of the computer.
>
> Is this supposed to be this way? How can I obtain my license?

Depending on how you ordered it this might have been the way it was intended.

If you ordered  Windows 7 professional 64 bit as a full product to be bundles with your installation (and the price rose a 100 Euro-ish) then no. You should have a proper working CoA sticker.

If you just selected 'windows 7 prof x64' from a menu while configuring the laptop then you probably ordered thre OEM version. That one is usualy activated by a key in the BIOS and there is no need to actually ship a laptop with a CoA.

Despite this many laptops ship with a OEM installed OS version, a matching key in the BIOS **and** a CoA. To use this CoA you will need the matching regular ISO and not the OEM prepped version.

OK, with all this background out of the way: CoA tended to get worn down. Putting some tape over it helped, but most were still unreadable after a year or five. Many manufacturers solved this problem by moving the CoA to a different place than the bottom of the laptop. In the case of your laptop it is behind the battery.

> Also, is it recommended to have a clean installation and get rid of
> the Lenovo software stuff>

Yes. Yes it is.